# Cannot read req.body in Next.js 13 middeware

Tags: javascript, next.js, zod, next.js13

In the code below I want to validate the request body with a schema from zod, currently, it will fail and catch. This is because `req.body` is returning a `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>` and not the object that it expects to parse.

```
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
  if (pathname.startsWith('/api/user/create')) {
    try {
      createUserSchema.parse({
        body: req.body,
        params: req.nextUrl.searchParams,
      });
      return NextResponse.next();
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(req.body);
      return NextResponse.json(
        { success: false, message: error },
        { status: 422, headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' } }
      );
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

this below is the output of the `console.log(req.body);`

```
<ref *1> ReadableStream {
  _state: 'readable',
  _reader: undefined,
  _storedError: undefined,
  _disturbed: false,
  _readableStreamController: ReadableStreamDefaultController {
  _controlledReadableStream: [Circular *1],
  _queue: S {
  _cursor: 0,
  _size: 0,
  _front: { _elements: [], _next: undefined },
  _back: { _elements: [], _next: undefined }
},
  _queueTotalSize: 0,
  _started: false,
  _closeRequested: false,
  _pullAgain: false,
  _pulling: false,
  _strategySizeAlgorithm: [Function],
  _strategyHWM: 1,
  _pullAlgorithm: [Function],
  _cancelAlgorithm: [Function]
}
}
```

I did some research and found that I need to run some kind of conversion method on this ReadableStream. The problem is that most of these include the Buffer module which cannot be run on the Edge and therefore cannot work in the `middleware.ts`. Is there perhaps a polyfill that I can use?

`"next": "^13.0.7"`
`Node v16.17.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next.js middleware does not work the same as an Express middleware because it only runs on navigation and does not act as a catch-all for your API endpoints.

As per [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware), you can only access cookies, access/modify request headers and perform redirects and rewrites using this feature.

Comment: But is there a way to implement what I am trying to do (validate a post request body in a middleware before hitting endpoint)? Can I add custom express middleware to an api route or am I limited to the Next.js middleware.ts?

Comment: I have moved this logic to the individual api endpoint as per @emeraldsanto's response and the Next.js middleware documentation that states the following: ``To respect the differences in client-side and server-side navigation, and to help ensure that developers do not build insecure Middleware, we are removing the ability to send response bodies in Middleware. This ensures that Middleware is only used to rewrite, redirect, or modify the incoming request (e.g. setting cookies).``

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
const body = await req.json()
```

Comment: If you send empty body from postman you're going to encounter with `Unexpected end of JSON input` error